# Enforce no pagebreak between a KOMA float (\DeclareNewTOC) and an mdframed environment

Tags: koma-script, mdframed

The code

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newmdenv[
  usetwoside=false,
  leftmargin = \dimexpr-1em-3pt,
  innerleftmargin = 1em,
  innertopmargin = 0pt,
  innerbottommargin = 0pt,
  innerrightmargin = 0pt,
  rightmargin = 0pt,
  linewidth = 3pt,
  linecolor = orange,
  skipbelow = 0pt,
  backgroundcolor = yellow!20,
  topline = true,
  rightline = false,
  bottomline = false
]{highlighted}

\newmdenv[
  usetwoside=false,
  leftmargin = \dimexpr-1em-3pt,
  innerleftmargin = 1em,
  innertopmargin = 0pt,
  innerbottommargin = 0pt,
  innerrightmargin = 0pt,
  rightmargin = 0pt,
  linewidth = 3pt,
  linecolor = orange,
  skipabove= 0pt,
  skipbelow = \parskip,
  topline = false,
  rightline = false,
  bottomline = false,
  footnoteinside = false,
  nobreak = false
]{sidebaronly}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  category=float,
  float,% declares floating environment eq
  floatpos=ht,
  nonfloat,% declares non-floating environment eq-
  listname={Some Special Stuff},
  name=TM,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylevel:=table,
  tocentryindent:=table,
  tocentrynumwidth:=table,
  type=MySpecialEnvFloat,
]{ltm}


\newcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MySpecialEnv}[4]{%
    \refstepcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}%
    \begin{samepage} 

    \begin{MySpecialEnvFloat-}
    \begin{highlighted}
        \textbf{TM\,\theMySpecialEnvCounter}: #2
    \end{highlighted}
    \addcontentsline{ltm}{section}{TM\,\theMySpecialEnvCounter: #2}
    \label{#1}%
    \end{MySpecialEnvFloat-}
    \zref@labelbyprops{#1}{MySpecialEnvId,MySpecialEnvDefinition,MySpecialEnvPL}%
    \begin{sidebaronly}
        \setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
        \protect{#4}
    \end{sidebaronly}
    \end{samepage}
}%  

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\listofMySpecialEnvFloats

\MySpecialEnv{test-id}{Something that looks like a summary}{-}{
  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here
  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here
  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here
}

\MySpecialEnv{test-id-2}{Yet another summary}{-}{
  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here
  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here
  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here
}

\end{document}
```

yields an environment that easily breaks across pages after the highlighted region. I want this to break **everywhere else**, but how?

[image: Showing a break across pages]

Also any idea how to make the orange side line not be interrupted?

**Update 2022-02-11**

Folowing Ulrike's proposal and after a long night eading the docs I am here with my goal nearly reached if someone can explain me how I can have back a parskip like in regular text.

```latex
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode, psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  category=float,
  float,% declares floating environment eq
  floatpos=ht,
  nonfloat,% declares non-floating environment eq-
  listname={Some Special Stuff},
  name=TM,
  tocentrystyle=tocline,
  tocentrylevel:=table,
  tocentryindent:=table,
  tocentrynumwidth:=table,
  type=MySpecialEnvFloat,
]{ltm}

\newtcolorbox[
    auto counter,
    crefname={TM}{TMs}]{MyBox}[2][]{
    breakable,
    sharp corners=all,
    left skip=\dimexpr-1em-3pt,
    leftrule=3pt,
    rightrule=-1pt,
    toprule=3pt,
    toprule at break=-1pt,
    bottomrule=-1pt,
    bottomrule at break=-1pt,
    colback=white,
    colframe=orange,
    colbacktitle=yellow!20,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    titlerule=0pt,
    colupper=blue,
    subtitle style={boxrule=0.4pt, rightrule=-1pt,
            colback=yellow!20}, 
    title={TM\,\thetcbcounter: #2},
    #1}

\newcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MySpecialEnv}[4]{%
    \refstepcounter{MySpecialEnvCounter}%

    \begin{MyBox}[label={#1}]{#2}
      \addcontentsline{ltm}{section}{TM\,\theMySpecialEnvCounter: #2}
      Some text 
      \tcblower
      #4
    \end{MyBox}
}%  

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\listofMySpecialEnvFloats

Varioref test: Reference to \vref{test-id} and \vref{test-id-2}


\MySpecialEnv{test-id}{Something that looks like a summary}{-}{
  \lipsum[1]

  % There could be a page break here
  \lipsum[1]

  % There could be a page break here
  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here
}

\MySpecialEnv{test-id-2}{Yet another summary}{-}{
  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here

  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here

  \lipsum[1]
  % There could be a page break here
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know a concrete solution but generally I would suggest to use tcolorbox instead of mdframed. tcolorbox is more powerful and is actively maintained. Also the breakable frames in mdframed are rather a pain, they often break when you don't want it. Be also careful where you issue the \refstepcounter. If you want to use hyperref later it will try to create a destination and this can lead to break points and change spacing. Better use the command near some text in horizontal mode.

Comment: Thank you for the hint to `tcolorbox`. Wrt to `\refstepcounter` I do not fully get your comment. Where would you put it? Directly after `\begin{highlighted}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see my implementation. Any hint how I can maintain the parskip like in regular text?

Comment: Are you looking for 'parbox=false,' ?

Comment: Yes, that is the solution

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have hard times to stpre values inside the `tcolorbox` using `\@namedef` or `\xsbox` and retriev them later within another `tcolorbox`. Any idea how to deal with those?

Comment: A tcolorbox creates like all other environments a group,  local definitions are lost when you quit the group.

Comment: And how to amend this? The problem: `tcolorbox` definitions have to appear before `\begin{document}` while all macros based on `zref[user]` require being passed `\begin{document}`.